# Showing $\log_b{n} = O(n^p)$ for all $b > 1$ and all $p > 0$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I've been asked to show, using $\log_b{x} = \frac{\log_a{x}}{\log_a{b}}$ and that $\log_2{n} = O(n^\frac{1}{p})$ and $n^p = O(2^n)$, that $\log_b{n} = O(n^p)$.

I have no idea where to start for this, and I'm unsure of what method to use to prove it for all $b>1$ and $p>0$.

How do I prove this using what I've been told?

Answer (score 0):

You have $\log_b n=O(\log_2 n)$, by the change of base formula for logarithm, and as $\log_2 n = O\bigl(n^\frac{1}{p}\bigr)$, there results by the usual rules of asymptotic analysis, that
$$\log_b n = O\bigl(n^\frac{1}{p}\bigr)\qquad\text{for every }b>1.$$

*Note*: as we actually have $\log_b n=o(\log_2 n)$, there results a stronger result:
$$\log_b n = o\bigl(n^\frac{1}{p}\bigr)\qquad\text{for every }b>1$$

Comment: Thank you! How do I show it for $O(n^p)$ using that result though?

Comment: Still easier: $log_b(n)=o(n^p)$ since it is known from high-school that $\ln(n)=o(n^\alpha)$ for any $\alpha>0$ (of course in high school, they do not see the asymptotic notations, but they know the limit that this notation means).